# How to translate "take Catholic orders"?

Tags: translation

To become a Buddhist "monk" or "nun" is called *chūjiā* 出家. What is it called to take Catholic orders, other than *dāng shénfù* 當神父, etc.?

---

**Edit** (after reading some comments): A former Dominican novice told me that 出家 is sometimes used in the case of taking monastic orders. I'd be especially interested to hear from other people who have first-hand experience with this calling in a Chinese-language context.

Comment: What exactly does taking catholic orders mean?

Comment: take the vows of a （catholic) nun（monk）
 发誓成为一个(天主教)修女 （(天主教)修道士） (神父 priest)

Comment: Taking orders means undergoing the formal ritual of commitment to the life of a Catholic priest or nun, monastic or "secular". "Take holy orders" is another way of expressing this. Today I heard that 出家 is in fact sometimes used in this sense, if one is joining a monastic order.

Answer (score 3):

**Holy orders**

*Oxford*

> 圣秩
>
> to take holy orders
>
> 领受圣秩

*21st Century*

> 1 圣职受任仪式
>
> 2 牧师职位
>
> 3 牧师的品位等级

KEY, ABC, A Chinese-English Dictionary, Grand Ricci all call this:

> 神品

Liang-An also calls it `神品` saying:

> 也作［圣品］、［圣秩］

Comment: 领受圣秩 is closest to the structure of "to take holy orders", but I wonder if more native-sounding expressions have emerged. I see 神品 in a few sources, but I don't see examples. It looks like a noun; what verbal collocations does it possess?

Comment: I guess the 品 in 神品 renders something like "official rank".

Comment: @brannerchinese according to Chinese wikipedia entry [聖秩聖事](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/聖秩聖事), it may also be called `晉鐸` (「晉升司鐸」, become a priest), but it doesn't sound "native" either. Anyway, this concept is quite unique and may sound exotic, I'm afraid there's no well-known expression.

Comment: Note that 牧师 refers to a clergy in the Protestant denominations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the phrase might be `担任圣职` or `授任圣职`.

[Here](http://www.chinacatholic.org/News/show/id/30761.html)'s an article talking about Pope Francis. It uses `担任圣职`.

As for the second translation, here's a quote from `The Three Musketeers` (in [English](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1257/1257-h/1257-h.htm)):

> "Ordination!" cried d'Artagnan.

is translated in [Chinese](https://books.google.com/books?id=fgycZH5oQfEC&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=%E5%9C%A3%E8%81%8C%E6%8E%88%E4%BB%BB) as:

> “圣职授任礼！” 达达尼昂叫起来

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 入教？ It doesn't mean for being a godfather (or similar) in Buddhist. But it is the equivalent of 出家 in some level.